# How do I install PyMOL on 64 bit Windows 7 SP1?

Tags: windows-7, installation, python

I would like to install PyMOL on my PC. I un-installed it yesterday because I previously installed python 2.7.9 via Python(x,y) while my PyMOL installation (which I installed months ago so I'm afraid I forgot how I did so) was using python 2.7.8 and the result was that PyMOL was no longer working properly, e.g., look at this screenshot I took, the GUI molecule viewer wasn't visible, just the console.

[image]

I have tried using wheels files (namely http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pymol amd64 version) but I have encountered pip problems. See the pip I have came along with my 64-bit Python 2.7.9 installation and the exe file for pip is called pip2.exe. So I changed the system environment variable `PYTHONPATH` to `C:\Python27` (where the python installation is) and `PATH` to `C:\Python27\Scripts` which is where `pip2.exe` is (along with pip2.7.exe, easy_install.exe and easy_install-2.7.exe, if relevant). Then I ran:

```
pip2 install pymol-1.7.2.1-cp27-none-win_amd64.whl
```

from the command prompt, but this gave the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\runpy.py", line 162, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", fname, loader, pkg_name)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\runpy.py", line 72, in _run_code
    exec code in run_globals
  File "C:\Python27\Scripts\pip2.exe\__main__.py", line 5, in <module>
ImportError: No module named pip
```

## Edit: #1

I uninstalled python and reinstalled it (64 bit again) as I suspected some errors had occurred in my previous installation (this time the pip that came with it included a file called pip.exe in the Scripts folder), then I ran the pymol installation command again (after running `pip install wheel-0.24.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl`, downloaded from with this file downloaded from https://pypi.python.org/packages/py2.py3/w/wheel/wheel-0.24.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl#md5=4c24453cda2177fd42c5d62d6434679a) and received a different error, the pip.log file may be found here: http://goo.gl/ORVNPB.

## A further attempt

I then downloaded https://codeload.github.com/evonove/pymol/zip/1.7.4, extracted its contents and ran

> python setup.py build install

This gave the output:

```
running build
running build_py
running build_ext
building 'pymol._cmd' extension
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup.py", line 349, in <module>
    data_files  = data_files
  File "C:\Python27\lib\distutils\core.py", line 151, in setup
    dist.run_commands()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 953, in run_commands
    self.run_command(cmd)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 972, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\distutils\command\build.py", line 127, in run
    self.run_command(cmd_name)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 326, in run_command
    self.distribution.run_command(command)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 972, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\distutils\command\build_ext.py", line 337, in run
    self.build_extensions()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\distutils\command\build_ext.py", line 446, in build_exte
nsions
    self.build_extension(ext)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\distutils\command\build_ext.py", line 496, in build_exte
nsion
    depends=ext.depends)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\distutils\msvc9compiler.py", line 473, in compile
    self.initialize()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\distutils\msvc9compiler.py", line 383, in initialize
    vc_env = query_vcvarsall(VERSION, plat_spec)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\distutils\msvc9compiler.py", line 299, in query_vcvarsal
l
    raise ValueError(str(list(result.keys())))
ValueError: [u'path']
```

Comment: Based on the errors in your screenshot.  It looks like you have bit-version mismatch.

Comment: You can also just change the filename from `pip2.7.exe` to `pip2.exe`

Comment: Too late to dwell on the screenshot errors, I'm afraid as I've already uninstalled it. Now I'm using just 64 bit programs: python and whl files for pymol